# Só que ela precisa calcular o resultado dessa fórmula para vários valores de x

Tags: python, ipython-notebook

(x**2 - 4*x + 5). Só que ela precisa calcular o resultado dessa fórmula para vários valores de x.

Formato de entrada: Dois números inteiros, um em cada linha:

O primeiro número (a) representa o primeiro valor de x que deve ser utilizado
O segundo número (b) representa o último valor de x que deve ser utilizado

Formato de saída: Os resultados de x**2 - 4*x + 5, para x no intervalo fechado entre a e b no domínio dos números inteiros.

OBS: os resultados serão sempre números inteiros, não é necessário realizar arredondamentos.

Já tentei dessa forma, porém não tive sucesso:

```
x = int(input(''))
x1 = int(input(''))


conta = ((x**2 ) - (4*x) + 5)
conta1 = ((x1**2 ) - (4*x1) + 5)
print(conta)
print(conta1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma função onde o parametro é o x para fazer os calculos:

```
def f(x):
    return (x**2) - (4*x) + 5
```

Aqui você recebe os valores do usuário:

```
x1 = int(input('Inicial: '))
x2 = int(input('Final: '))
```

Aqui você itera sobre o range de números inicial e final digitado pelo usuário, dessa forma você chama a função para cada valor do range:

```
for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
    print(f'resultado da conta: {f(x)}')
```